# Robotics - Recursive function for fractal.

Tags: python, recursion, robotics, myro, calico-project

I'm currently working with Myro/Calico with Robotics.  I'm trying to run a recursive function of a fractal. I'm using Python.

I've been following pseudocode here.
[Fractal](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Recursion_and_Fractals)

So far I've tried to implement the first step without recursion.  And it runs well

```
# 1 foot per 2 seconds.  x * 2 = feet desired.  
def fractal(x):
    waitTime = x*2
    turnRight(1, 0.825) #90 degree turn
    forward(1, x/3) #move length/3 steps
    turnLeft(1, 0.55)#60 degree turn
    forward(1, x/3) #move length/3 steps
    turnRight(1, 1.1) #120 degree turn
    forward(1, x/3) #move length/3 steps
    turnLeft(1, 0.55) #60 degree turn
    forward(1, x/3) #move length/3 steps
```

While this works, my goal is to go through this recursively, but make a smaller curve at each iteration.  I attempted to do it, but my robot isn't moving as desired.

Here's my attempt at recursion

```
def fractal(x):
    waitTime = x*2
    if (x == 1):
        forward(x/3)
    else:
        (x-1)/3
    turnLeft(1,0.55) #60 degrees
    if (x == 1):
        forward(x/3)
    else:
        (x-1)/3
    turnRight(1, 1.1) #120 degree turn
    if (x == 1):
        forward(x/3)
    else:
        (x-1)/3
    turnLeft(1, 0.55)#60 degree turn
    if (x == 1):
        forward(x/3)
    else:
        (x-1)/3
```

My robot is only turning left and right, but it's not making the full shape.  The one without the recursion started the fractal.  I just need recursion to go through the whole fractal.

Comment: How are you calling fractal?  And from what I see there is no recursion here.

Comment: I'm putting fractal(3) to specify the feet I want to go. You can put any number in. I tried following the pseudo on the site I linked. How would I make that recursive?

Comment: Just so you know, `else: (x-1)/3` doesn't do anything. Did you mean to do `forward((x-1)/3)` or `x = (x-1)/3` or `fractal((x-1)/3)` or something?

Comment: Ohh.. thanks kevin.  I meant whatever variable the user puts in , say 5, would become (5-1)/3.  That's not happening?   I guess I should do x = (x-1)/3?

Comment: I don't believe that is what you want I'm looking at the pseudocode now and you should be calling fractal inside the else but fractal should take 2 inputs. 1 for the length the other for the number of iterations

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to have two variables to `fractal` instead of just one. You can't easily represent the fractal depth _and_ the width of the curve with just one variable. What if I want a five iteration Koch curve that's 100 pixels wide? What would the call to `fractal` look like, and how would it differ if I wanted a seven iteration curve that's 100 pixels wide?

Comment: Oh... I think I know what you're saying.  do a whole new fractal(x) inside each else.  So one for length, the other for variations..  My robot moves at 2 feet per one second.  I can't really specify length.. it's not built in. But I guess I can create some type of length.  If I want a length of 5 feet, I would put waitTime*2 in the parameter?  That would make it go 10 feet I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this is what you want to do

```
x = number of interations
l = lenth(wait time)
def fractal(x, l):
    if (x == 1):
        forward(l/3)
    else:
        fractal((x-1), l/3)
    turnLeft(1,0.55) #60 degrees
    if (x == 1):
        forward(l/3)
    else:
        fractal((x-1), l/3)
    turnRight(1, 1.1) #120 degree turn
    if (x == 1):
        forward(l/3)
    else:
        fractal((x-1), l/3)
    turnLeft(1, 0.55)#60 degree turn
    if (x == 1):
        forward(l/3)
    else:
        fractal((x-1), l/3)
```

Comment: No problem recursion is a hard problem to wrap your head around at first.  If you're interested in recursion and programming one of the easiest to start with is Fibonacci.